# I am getting 403 with scrapy and it is work perfectly from browser and wget

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl avito.ru and using very simple Spider:

```
class AvitoRu(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'avito_ru'

    def __init__(self, city=None, days=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AvitoRu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   
    def start_requests(self):

        url='https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/s_probegom/'
        request = scrapy.Request(url, self.parse,  headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3',
})  
        yield request
```

But it is not working. I am getting 403 error. Avito.ru use redirection in browser. So how I can watch exactlly request from my spider. With headers, body... explained. Are there any option or log file? Because I dont understand the difference between request from browser and scrapy. It must be the same.... but... one is working, another one - not.

Comment: Can you show the console logs?

Comment: INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
<GET https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/s_probegom/>
DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/s_probegom/> (referer: None)
INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/s_probegom/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Comment: But in browser you will get redirect (301) instead of 403. From https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/s_probegom to https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/s_probegom-ASgBAgICAUSGFMjmAQ

Comment: Okay, see if this answer will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759724/9339732

Comment: No, please look at my initial question. It is already contains user-agent

Comment: But you should also add it as an attribute of the spider, just in case the headers are overridden. in `__init__` add `self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3'`

Comment: Not working... :(